# trouble defining weakly defined ref cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to write a stored proc that takes in a number, n, and returns the first n results for a given query, exclusively locking those n rows.  I'm a little new to SQL and I'm having a bit of difficulty matching data types correctly.

My package spec looks like this:

```
PACKAGE package IS
   Type out_result_type is REF CURSOR;
   PROCEDURE stored_proc
     (in_n IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10, 
        out_list IN OUT out_result_type);
```

I then define the cursor in the procedure body, like so:

```
CURSOR OUT_RESULT_TYPE IS
        SELECT a.id
            FROM schema.table a
            WHERE (some conditions) AND rownum <= in_n;
```

A bit later on I then try to extract the results of the cursor into the output variable:

```
OPEN OUT_RESULT_TYPE;
FETCH OUT_RESULT_TYPE INTO out_list; -- error on this line
CLOSE OUT_RESULT_TYPE;
```

But alas this code doesn't compile; oracle complains that out_list has already been defined with a conflicting data type.  Any idea how I can resolve this issue?  It's driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test
AS
        TYPE    tt_cur IS REF CURSOR;
        PROCEDURE prc_cur (retval OUT tt_cur);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test
AS
        PROCEDURE prc_cur (retval OUT tt_cur)
        AS
        BEGIN
                OPEN    retval
                FOR
                SELECT  *
                FROM    dual;
        END;
END;
```

If you want to lock, use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test
AS
        PROCEDURE prc_cur (retval OUT tt_cur)
        AS
        BEGIN
                OPEN    retval
                FOR
                SELECT  a.id
                FROM    schema.table a
                WHERE   (some conditions)
                        AND rownum <= in_n
                ORDER BY
                        column
                -- Never forget ORDER BY!
                FOR UPDATE;
        END;
END;
```

Comment: @tuinstoel: I always forget it exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `out_list` must be of wrong type. Consider (script run on 10.2.0.3):

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT ROWNUM ID FROM all_objects WHERE ROWNUM <= 100;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cursor_pck AS
   TYPE out_result_type is REF CURSOR;
   PROCEDURE stored_proc (p_in IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10, 
                          p_out_list IN OUT out_result_type);
END cursor_pck;
/
```

If you want to select and lock the rows at the same time you would use the `FOR UPDATE` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cursor_pck AS
   PROCEDURE stored_proc (p_in IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10,  
                          p_out_list IN OUT out_result_type) IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN p_out_list FOR SELECT a.id FROM t a WHERE ROWNUM <= p_in FOR UPDATE;
   END stored_proc;
END cursor_pck;
/
```

With the following setup, you will call the procedure like this:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_cursor cursor_pck.out_result_type;
  3     l_id t.id%TYPE;
  4  BEGIN
  5     cursor_pck.stored_proc(3, l_cursor);
  6     LOOP
  7        FETCH l_cursor INTO l_id;
  8        EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  9        dbms_output.put_line(l_id);
 10     END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /

1
2
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

1. A cursor doesn't lock.
2. You don't have to do `Type out_result_type is REF CURSOR;`, use default type sys_refcursor. See here: [Oracle - How to have an out ref cursor parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869055/oracle-how-to-have-an-out-ref-cursor-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure/869730#869730)

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work the way it's written, because

1. `out_list` expects a cursor, not a cursor result.
2. The name `out_result_type` is already used for a **type**, so you can't redefine it to be a **cursor** in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a pre-defined weak reference cursor: sys_refcursor.  In usage it would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test
AS
    PROCEDURE prc_cur (p_retval OUT sys_refcursor,
                       p_lookup IN  VARCHAR2);
END pkg_test;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test 
AS
    PROCEDURE prc_cur(p_retval OUT sys_refcursor
                      p_lookup IN  VARCHAR2) 
    IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN retval FOR SELECT a.value 
                          FROM tblname a 
                         WHERE a.id <= p_lookup;
    END prc_cur;
END pkg_test;
```

This saves you the trouble of needing to declare a type.  The sys_refcursor is a pointer to a result set from an open cursor.  If you are familiar with Java, it's the same concept as the java.sql.ResultSet object which provides a way to get at the results of a query.